# What is wrong with the way I'm setting up my listview?

Tags: java, android

Here's my main activity:

```
package com.dannytsegai.worldgeography;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ListView listview;
    private String[] mContinents;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        mContinents = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.continents_array);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item, mContinents);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



}
```

Here's my main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've gone through the code, but I can't figure out what's wrong with it for the life of me. Can someone please help me?

Comment: wwhat is the error you are seeing? is the app crashing? if yes, paste logcat here then

Comment: The app is crashing. Let me get my logcat real quick.

Comment: TAG: ArrayAdapter You must supply a resource ID for a textview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

> R.layout.simple_list_item

to

```
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

Comment: But my XML file is named "simple_list_item" not "simple_list_item_1"

Comment: seems like blackbelts and mine both anser need to be combined to get truly correct answer

Comment: Okay I got it now. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2):

since you are extending `ListActivity`, in the layout, your ListVeiw must have the id `@android:id/list`, otherwise you will get the following exeception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'.
```

To retrieve the `ListView` you do not need to call `findViewById` but you can use directly `getListView()` that returns the ListView

Comment: I did that but now I'm getting this error: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: Still getting an error. Why the hell is something this simple so complicated?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
             "Linux", "OS/2" };
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
           setListAdapter(adapter);
      }
}
```

If in doubt check this page: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listactivit